# signals sent by qtcreator on "stop"

Tags: linux, qt, signals, qt-creator

I am working on linux and I realized that my application was leaving behind daemon processes when I close it with the "Stop" button on Qt creator IDE. I want to handle these cases so the application close the same way as when I close the main window. To write the handlers, I need to know which signals it corresponds to.

Comment: That would be SIGTERM I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Digging into QtCreator's code, I can see that QtCreator uses a QProcess internally to launch your app. The red "stop" button is connected to `ApplicationLauncher::stop()`, which terminates your process in one of two ways depending if it's a GUI app or a console app, but in both cases, the result end up to be the same on Linux.

For a GUI app, `ApplicationLauncher` calls `QProcess::terminate()`, which in turn sends a SIGTERM (on Linux) signal to your daemon. It then waits (with `waitForFinished()`) for 1 second, and if the daemon hasn't quit by then, it calls `QProcess::kill()`, sending `SIGKILL`.

For a console app, `ApplicationLauncher` delegates the termination to the `ConsoleProcess` utility class. On Linux, `ConsoleProcess::stop()` will act similar to `ApplicationLauncher` for a GUI app, which is first sending `SIGTERM`, then waiting for 1 second, and sending `SIGKILL` if it hasn't terminated yet.

You will find the relevant code from QtCreator here:

- [GUI app termination](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/2.6/src/plugins/projectexplorer/applicationlauncher.cpp#line173)
- [Console app termination (on Linux)](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/2.6/src/libs/utils/consoleprocess_unix.cpp#line163)
- [Console app termination (on Windows)](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/2.6/src/libs/utils/consoleprocess_win.cpp#line158)

Comment: @Fred So the relevant code links apply to "Running" an application - however of course these blocks are irrelevant when "Debugging" an application. Any idea where to corresponding stop/kill operations are for debugging? Perhaps it simply instructs gdb to perform this kill timeout action somehow?

Comment: Links no longer work. Suitable link for the UNIX-related source code: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qt-creator/src/libs/utils/consoleprocess_unix.cpp.html#_ZN5Utils14ConsoleProcess4stopEv

Answer (score 1):

Short version: You can't

Long version:

You could try using:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit

But this won't work as expected. If a process is terminated by force (which is what the stop in the IDE is doing, I'd guess using TerminateProcess() on windows http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx ) then the process is instantly killed in the middle of whatever it is executing. Its not possible to handle these cases from Qt alone.