# Handling Signal Sent by "Stop" While Running Debugger in QT Creator

Tags: debugging, qt-creator, exit, signal-handling, sigterm

While running my program normally in QT Creator (on a Linux machine), when I hit the "stop" button, I am able to handle the SIGTERM signal and gracefully shut down my software. However, when I run in debug mode and hit the same button, no signal appears to be executed and the program just dies. Does the stop button while running in debug mode send some other signal, and if so what signal? Is it even possible to handle this from within QT Creator? Does it send a signal I can't even handle such as SIGKILL? I can gracefully shut the software done in debug mode if I issue a SIGTERM signal to the process of my software, but I was hoping there was a way I could do this within QT Creator as opposed to using another terminal window.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [signals sent by qtcreator on "stop"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137808/signals-sent-by-qtcreator-on-stop)